# How to access an array that is returned from a function in Smarty?

Tags: php, arrays, smarty

I have a very complicated object `$obj`. It has a method `getDim($subObjId)` which returns an array.

In PHP I can access the array via `$obj->getDim(1)['height']`. (I think this works since PHP 5.5)

Now I want to do the same in Smarty, since the object has so many properties, that I don't want to convert the whole object into an array.

But I cannot find the right syntax. Is there an equivalent smarty syntax to the example above?

I tried (without success):

```
{$obj->getDim(1).height}
{$obj->getDim(1)[height]}
{($obj->getDim(1))[height]}
{($obj->getDim(1)).height}
{$obj->getDim(1)->height}
```

However, at the moment I use

```
{$dim = $obj->getDim(1)}{$dim.height}
```

This works fine, but I would like to get rid of the assignment step.

**Edit**

The context of my problem looks more like this:

```
{foreach $listOfIds as $id}
   {for $i = 0 to $obj->getDim($id).height step 10}
      ...
   {/for}
{/foreach}
```

Comment: isn't running functions in your template code sort of contrary the point of using a template engine?

Comment: @errata I avoid whenever it is possible. But this time avoiding it would result in horrible work. But in general you are right.

Comment: are you looping through several items or just passing the single object?

Comment: @errata I'm looping though a list of IDs, but it is only one `$obj`. It looks more like `{$obj->getDim($id) ...`

Comment: is there a reason you dont just call the function and pass the result directly into your template from the controller?

Comment: @errata The reason is that I would have to do this with a *lot* of data. I think it would make the code much less readable and converting everything into a array (or many arrays) would slow the page down.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is still a thing as I haven't used Smarty in a long time and it seems a little abusive but there is php tag

```
{php} echo $obj->getDim(1).height; {/php}
```

http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.php.tpl

Comment: Oh, this is great. I thought one should never use `{php}` in smarty but, this seems to be a case where one have to. But I'm also very sorry: I think I cannot use this. I abstracted my example too much... I have to use this inside another smarty command. Please have a look at my updated question (the context at the end)